# Write the biggest prime

Tags: c#, algorithm, numbers, primes

I'm trying to solve [the biggest prime](http://programmingpraxis.com/2013/02/08/the-biggest-prime/) programming praxis problem in C#.
The problem is simple, print out or write to file the number:
2<sup>57,885,161</sup> − 1 (which has 17,425,170 digits)

I have managed to solve it using the amazing [GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) through [Emil Stevanof .Net wrapper](http://www.emilstefanov.net/Projects/GnuMpDotNet/)

```
var num = BigInt.Power(2, 57885161) - 1;
File.WriteAllText("biggestPrime.txt", num.ToString());
```

Even if all the currently posted solutions use this library, to me it feels like cheating. Is there a way to solve this in managed code? Ideas? Suggestions?

PS: I have already tried using .Net 4.0 [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) but it *never* ends to compute (I waited 5 minutes but it is already a lot compared to 50 seconds of the GMP solution).

Comment: I'll just point out that 5 minutes is not *[never](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)*

Comment: The `BigInteger.ToString()` method is _very_ slow for big numbers. Also I don't quite understand why they chose to make `BigInteger` a value type, given that it's underlying array can take up many megabytes.

Comment: @Blachshma I know, that's why *never* is italic :) BTW I left it running after posting and it is still computing after more than 1 hour.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Why does it matter that it's a value type? Copying `BigInteger` means copying just the *reference* to the (possibly huge) array, not copying the whole array.

Comment: Another way to “cheat”: the problem statement doesn't say that you have to write the number in *decimal*, writing it in hexadecimal might be faster.

Comment: @svick: In that case you can just write "10", which is the correct number in base 2^57885161 - 1.

Comment: @svick In binary it is just a sequence of `57885161` ones. So all you need to do is figure out the first hex digit and the number of `f`s that follow. From `57885161 = 1 (mod 4)` the first digit is `1`, and the number of `f`s that follow is `57885161 / 4 = 14471290`.

Comment: @svick Maybe it doesn't matter (`BigInteger` being a value type). If one does `BigInteger copy = someBigInteger` it is only the reference to the underlying `byte[]` which is copied. The array itself is reused. And since `BigInteger` is immutable, there's no problem with that. But it's comparable to `System.String` which is also immutable, and which has a reference to a `char[]`. So why make `string` a reference type and `BigInteger` a value type? Both have value equality semantics with their `.Equals(object)` overrides and their overloads of the `==` operator.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Except that `string` doesn't actually have a reference to `char[]` (a managed array). `string` is special, and its `char`s are stored directly in the object, without another indirection. Changing `BigInteger` to `class` would add overhead without any benefit.

Comment: @svick no, the problem specifically asks for 17,425,170 digits. You only get that in decimal: `ceiling (57885161 / logBase 2 10) = 17425170`.

Comment: @svick I think now I do understand why they made `BigInteger` a value type. Thanks.

Comment: Of course, calling `.ToString("X")` on a `System.Numerics.BigInteger` is _very_ fast since it's just a concatenation of the hex values of all the bytes; no conversion calculation needed.

Comment: On my machine GMP took five seconds to get the prime in decimal.  I have a 2 GHz i7.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's also more a cheat than a solution but I solved this using the [IntX library](http://intx.codeplex.com/)

```
IntX.Pow(2, 57885161, MultiplyMode.AutoFht) - 1;
```

It ran approximately 6 minutes. Still this is not a real answer though. Would be interesting to see something "real".

EDIT: Using a C# Stopwatch I figured that the calculation only took 5 seconds, it's the process of ToString that takes extremely long.

Comment: Considering that the library is written in full managed code it's good for me. I'll delve more into the IntX codebase. Thanks

Comment: The binary calculation of the number is rather trivial. With `BigInteger` it can also be written as `var prime = (((BigInteger)1) << 57885161) - 1;`. So it is the conversion to decimal which requires effort.

Comment: Same in GMP of course.  Calculating the prime in binary takes GMP 0.003 seconds.  Converting it to decimal takes about five seconds.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to calculate this number using just multiplications (and an appropriate large integer library) you can look at cutting down on the number of calculations made.  In the simple case you could repeatedly multiply by 2 (57885161 times) before deducing 1 but we can do it with significantly fewer multiplications.

Consider repeated squaring.  This gives us 2, 2<sup>2</sup>, (2<sup>2</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>4</sup>, (2<sup>4</sup>)<sup>2</sup> = 2<sup>8</sup>, etc...  After squaring 25 times we would have calculated 2<sup>(2<sup>25</sup>)</sup> = 2<sup>33554432</sup>.

If we look at the binary representation of 57885161 we get 11011100110100000111101001.  I.e. telling us we need (for 2<sup>57885161</sup>) 2<sup>(2<sup>25</sup>)</sup> * 2<sup>(2<sup>24</sup>)</sup> * 2<sup>(2<sup>22</sup>)</sup> etc... We can store all the required powers of 2 on our way to calculating the highest required one and then just do the final multiplications.  So thats 25 + 13 large integer multiplications.  We then just need to deduct 1 for the required value.

Comment: This will still be monumentally slow unless an advanced algorithm is used for the large integer multiplications.

Answer (score -5):

What you what to achieve is computational-intensive. Visual C# and Visual Basic (and interpreted languages in general) are not designed for such a thing. Using the GMP is *the proper thing to do*, as it is implemented in pure C and highly optimized for execution speed.

If you choose to use managed code only, then *be patient*: Using .Net 4.0 BigInteger may take up to *100 times more* time than using the GMP. To test this, you should compute 2<sup>1,000</sup>, 2<sup>10,000</sup>, 2<sup>100,000</sup>, 2<sup>1,000,000</sup> and 2<sup>10,000,000</sup> and see how much time it takes to compute each of these expressions using the .Net 4.0 Framework.

If it turns out that the needed time is too long, then you could try and make the computations yourself. You should use this [algorithm to perform the exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) and then port from C++ to C# [my own implementation of big integers multiplication](https://github.com/spatarel/algos/blob/master/HugeInt.cpp) or any other that you may find. However, there is *no guarantee* that you will achieve a significantly better performance, since you are still using managed code.

Comment: C# and VB are not interpreted languages, they are compiled down to IL, which is then compiled to machine code. There is no reason why managed code should be 100 times slower than the same code in C.

Comment: The poster does not make the statement that C#/VB are interpreted per se. Other than that one might make the case that they use a runtime that interprets the resulting bytecode (pre/ecno/normal jit). Thirdly, language fanboys should actually read and understand the answer and consider the relevancy to the OP's question.

Comment: The OP states that using GMP the computation takes 50 seconds while using the .Net Framework the same computation is not complete even after more than one hour. Whatever the reasons, the fact is that C# and VB are not suited for computational-intensive operations and one should resort to other programming languages in such cases.

Comment: Using the IntX library (that is written in managed code) takes 10 times more, which is impressive. The purpose of my question was not to find the best and fastest solution in .net I just wanted to know a way to handle this in managed code.

Comment: This has almost nothing to do with the language and everything to do with the algorithm.  That is probably why this answer is getting downvoted.  When you are comparing the O(N^2) grade school approach to the O(N log N log log N) of IntX and GMP, the apparent multiplicative factor of seven from the language (IntX vs. GMP) is insignificant compared to the order factor when N is 58 million.  The wrong language makes it take a few minutes instead of a minute.  The wrong algorithm will make it take two years instead of a minute!  This answer is barking up the wrong tree.